# Featuretools failed to load plugin tsfresh from library featuretools_tsfresh_primitives.__init__

Tags: python, deep-learning, feature-engineering, featuretools

I'm trying to make featuretools and featuretools_tsfresh_primitives in my Jupyter notebook environment.

I installed both library using conda

```bash
    conda install -c conda-forge featuretools
    conda install -c conda-forge featuretools-tsfresh-primitives
```

However, when I tried using them, first I get a warning

```
>>> import featuretools
2023-07-28 08:48:31,448 featuretools - WARNING    Featuretools failed to load plugin tsfresh from library featuretools_tsfresh_primitives.__init__. For a full stack trace, set logging to debug.
```

I ran the import again inside a file after setting the logging level to DEBUG, but I didn't throw anything useful

The script:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

import featuretools
```

The output:

```
INFO:numexpr.utils:NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
2023-07-28 08:53:19,424 featuretools - WARNING    Featuretools failed to load plugin tsfresh from library featuretools_tsfresh_primitives.__init__. For a full stack trace, set logging to debug.
```

However, I can import the libraries on its own apparently.

```
>>> import featuretools as ft
2023-07-28 08:56:11,150 featuretools - WARNING    Featuretools failed to load plugin tsfresh from library featuretools_tsfresh_primitives.__init__. For a full stack trace, set logging to debug.
>>> ft.__version__
'1.27.0'

>>> import featuretools_tsfresh_primitives as fttp
>>> fttp.__version__
'1.0.2'

>>> ts.__version__
'0.20.1'
```

I'm very confused because I installed these same libraries in a different environment (it was Python 3.11 while this one is 3.10) and there is no issue with that installation. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow creating a conda environment through Anaconda Prompt solved the issue. Maybe my installation was polluted or something.